# how to fix CConsoleApplication.user undefined in a command class in yii framework?

Tags: php, yii, yiic

I am having that error , whenever I ran my simple cron script in shell , 
any idea how to fix that thing ?, from the error itself, it says the .user is undefiend,
when I placed the

```
'user' => array(
    // enable cookie-based authentication
     'allowAutoLogin' => true,
 'loginUrl' => array('myaccount/blah/login'),
```

in the console config, it is looking for a "Class" ,, what class am i supposed to include in that array? , this user login url is using an LDAP stuff in loggin in and authentication, what should I do ?

Comment: Just add `class => 'CWebUser'` and it should work

Comment: the problem with adding the CWebUser class is that , am running a cron task..when I ran it with the CWebUser class, it is throwing an error `CConsoleApplication and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named getSession` ,what to do then ?

Comment: Right, web user for console app does not sound good. Where does it try to use that user? Do you have stack trace? Maybe it is not nessesary?

Comment: there's no stack trace at all, it's looking for the getSession() , when i added the CWebUser class..what should I do to prevent this and let the cron script run properly?

Comment: Ok, do not use that `CWebUser` class. If you enable `YII_DEBUG` it should print stack trace in console as well, try to find where it tries to use `CConsoleApplication.user`, see @schmunk answer as well.

Comment: YII_DEBUG is currently set to true in the index.php..but am not seeing any stacktrace at all, aside from those two errors am getting either when I include that User array, and then put the CWebUser in the User array

Comment: Please paste the full error message.

Comment: I quoted it in my reply with PeterM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved my problem by using update, instead of save in the script...no need to use user array and CWebUser class

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I had the exact same problem...apparently, have to use update() instead of save()...

Comment: Ehm... Excuse me, but... what are you talking about? There is not even a tiny mention about `save()` or `update()` in your question. I think others will really appreciate, if you answer and question would match a little bit closer. Now, your answer looks like an off-topic one.

Comment: You rejected the question completely!

Answer (score 4):

A *CConsoleApplication* is for handling offline tasks. For example, the application starts a cronjob within a linux system. The application checks each day if a registered user of your website should change his password, because it must be changed every 3 month. If the password expired send an email.
To preselecting the users you have set a scope condition to check the status of a user, as well as a scope to restricted signed in users on her own data:

```
    public function scopes(){
                 return array(...,
                    'user'    => array(
                                   'condition'=>'id='.Yii::app()->user->id, 
                                 ),
                    'active'  => array(
                                   'condition'=>'status='.self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
                                 ), ...
                        );
    }
```

Now, in your *CCA*-Code you use the ***active*** scope to get all users:
`$usersArray = User::model()->active()->findAll(); ...foreach...`. The Problem here is in the use of the extended class, the *CActiveRecord*-class. Mostly used as a class extension in models, which are stored in a database. In this *CActiveRecord*-class the *CActiveRecord->__call* function is used to get all stored scopes of a model. After that the class merged the actually requested scopes with the rest of the database criteria. The fact that all scopes are loaded first occures the error in loading the ***user***-scope, include `Yii::app()->user->id`. The *WebUser* is called and throws the exception 'CException' with message 'attribute "CConsoleApplication.user is not defined'. You wouldn't call the *WebUser*, but the automatism arrange this for you :-)

So, do it like [schmunk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291573/schmunk) says. Generate in your scope code an exception part where ensures that `Yii::app()->user` is not called:

```
 public function scopes(){
         if (Yii::app() instanceof CConsoleApplication) {
              $user = array(''); //no condition 
         }else{
              $user = array(
                        'condition'=>'id='.Yii::app()->user->id, 
                      );
         }
         return array(
              'user'    => $user,
              'active'  => array(
                                   'condition'=>'status='.self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
                           ), ...
         );
 }
```

I hope the explanation helps and perhaps also for other problems.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You can't use CWebUser in console application. Don't include it in your `config/console.php`

Long(er) answer: If you rely on a component, which needs CWebUser, you'll have to detect this in the component and create some kind of workaround for this case. Have a look at [this code piece](https://github.com/schmunk42/p3extensions/blob/ebbcb497e5029993821007e9c68d867815ba4e31/behaviors/P3MetaDataBehavior.php#L130) for an example how to detect, if you're running a console app.

Comment: as i said, if I don't include that array from my first post, when i run the script, it is looking for a class, and then when i put the CWebUser class within the array, it is looking for the getSession function when CConsoleApplication don't have it in the documentation..what to do?

Comment: The question is: Why is your `yiic` command using the user module?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
public static $console_user_id;

public function init() {
    if (Yii::app() instanceof CConsoleApplication) {
        if (self::$console_user_id) $this->id = self::$console_user_id;
        return false;
    }
    parent::init();
}
```

Comment: please put some hint about why this is a solution. which details are addressed by your code that were unhandled/not managed by the op?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Screened all answers given here and found some good point, but solved my problem my way, although it may not be the best.

First off all I had to figure out that my Cron Jon threw the aforementioned Exception because inside the Cron job I was running a script which had this part of code in it

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()) {...} else {...}
```

So the console threw the error since the user was not defined. I changed my code in such a way that I tested if the console was running it. The changed code is as follows:

```
$console = false;
try {
    $test = Yii::app()->user->isAdmin();
}
catch (CException $e)  {
    $console = true;
}
if($console || (!$console && Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()) {...} else {...}
```

As said, not perfect, but maybe a solution for someone.